# Решение задачи C4 из ЕГЭ на Perl

Tags: perl

Помогите реализовать решение задачи на Perl :

> На вход программе подаются сведения о сдаче экзаменов учениками 9-х классов некоторой средней школы. В первой строке сообщается количество учеников N, которое не меньше 10, но не превосходит 100, каждая из следующих N строк имеет следующий формат:
> <Фамилия> <Имя> <оценки>,
> где <Фамилия> – строка, состоящая не более чем из 20 символов, <Имя> – строка, состоящая не более чем из 15 символов, <оценки> – через пробел три целых числа, соответствующие оценкам по пятибалльной системе. <Фамилия> и <Имя>, а также <Имя> и <оценки> разделены одним пробелом. Пример входной строки:
> Иванов Петр 4 5 3
> Требуется написать как можно более эффективную программу (укажите используемую версию языка программирования, например, Borland Pascal 7.0), которая будет выводить на экран фамилии и имена трех худших по среднему баллу учеников. Если среди остальных есть ученики, набравшие тот же средний балл, что и один из трех худших, то следует вывести и их фамилии и имена.

Я застрял на работе с самими строками, я понимаю что нужно использовать хеши, где имя и фамилия будут ключами , а средний балл значением, но как это реализовать с минимум телодвижений не могу придумать.
Функция для подсчёта среднего балла :

```
sub GPA {
   my @balls = @_;
   my $sum = 0;
   foreach my $item(@balls){
      $sum += $item;
   }
   return $sum/scalar @balls;
}
```

Comment: А можно решить задачу не на Perl, а на PHP или С++, например? Если да, то я решу)

Comment: Увы, но мне нужно именно на Perl :)

Comment: Жаль...Perl`ом не владею....

Comment: я с перлом почти не знаком, но разве не прокатит такой алгоритм?

при вводе данных по каждому ученику, делаем сплит строки по символу пробела, т.е. получаем массив вида

    $arr("Фамилия", "Имя", "4", "3", "5");

для каждого ученика. сразу же присваиваем некоемому локальному массиву значение среднего бала, ключем используем связку Имя Фамилия

    $localArr[$arr[1].' '.$arr[2]] = average($arr[3], $arr[4], $arr[5]);

потом сортируем этот массив и выводим результат.

Примеры кода на пхп. Думаю для знающего `perl` перевести труда не составит

Comment: И ещё не как не могу решить проблему с кодировкой, на ubuntu никаких проблем не было, а на Windows 7 каракули

Comment: balls это муди, если что...

Comment: @karmadro4 ball -- шар, жаргон: яйцо (млекопитающего, не птицы/рептилии, там -- egg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Берём однострочник.

```
perl -alne 'push @{$h{sprintf "%.2f",($F[2]+$F[3]+$F[4])/3.0}}, "$F[0] $F[1]"; END{ print join "\n", map { join ", ", @{ $h{$_} } } grep {if ($c < 3){$c+=$#{$h{$_}}+1}} ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h )[0..2] }'
```

Параметры расшифровываем (см. perlrun)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    @F = split;
    push @{$h{sprintf "%.2f",($F[2]+$F[3]+$F[4])/3.0}}, "$F[0] $F[1]";
}
print join "\n", map { join ", ", @{ $h{$_} } } grep {if ($c < 3){$c+=$#{$h{$_}}+1}} ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h )[0..2];
```

Теперь смотрим

```
    `sprintf "%.2f",($F[2]+$F[3]+$F[4])/3.0` -- средний балл с точностью два знака после запятой (см. perlfunc).

push @{$h{sprintf "%.2f",($F[2]+$F[3]+$F[4])/3.0}}, "$F[0] $F[1]";
```

Здесь в качестве значения хеша %h по ключу "ср. балл" имеем массив (список), в который добавляем стоку "фамилия имя" (`"$F[0] $F[1]"`). В результате цикла имеем хеш, где ключи -- средние баллы, а значения -- списки учеников, имеющих этот балл.  Получаем что-то типа

```
{
  3.00 => ("Троечников Вася", "Троечников Витя", "Троечников Петя")
  3.33 => ("Получше Вася", "Получше Петя")
}
```

Закончился цикл (END в однострочнике, наследство awk), анализируем дальше:

```
sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h )
```

Понятно -- сортировка массива ключей -- средних баллов по возрастанию. `sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h )[0..2]` -- array slice (см. perldata) -- первые три элемента этого массива.

```
grep {if ($c < 3){$c+=$#{$h{$_}}+1}} (...)
```

Фильтрация. $c, точнее $main::c -- счётчик жертв или body counter(переменная глобальная). Изначально не инициализирован, но нам по барабану (нет -w). Неинициализирован -- значит 0. `$#{$h{$_}}` -- индекс последнего элемента массива, являющегося значением `$h{$_}` (Про `$_` -- в perlvar, про `$#` -- в perldata). Увеличение после сравнения -- понятно почему -- группа, где 3 достигается, должна войти. Если `$main::c` больше или равна 3, то результат всего выражения if -- "наглая ложь". (а ненулевые значения $main::c, выдаваемые иначе, трактуются как "святая истина"). В результате пропускаем группы, без которых плохишей меньше трёх. На выходе имеем отфильтрованный массив средних баллов.

```
map { join ", ", @{ $h{$_} } } (...)
```

Преобразуем то, что получилось. `$_` принимает последовательно значения массива-аргумента , как и grep. Аргумент -- отфильтрованные ср. баллы. `join ", ", @{$h{$_}}` -- из каждого списка двоечников делает строку, объединяя значения через ", ". В результате map получаем строки, где ученики набрали одинаковый балл. Про `print join "\n",` я промолчу, если кто сам догадается -- я не виноват

Надеюсь, что сильно не наврал.

Comment: Классно написано.

Comment: Спасибо. Я старался.

Comment: Спасибо. Познавательно. Но перл - для особых мозгов ))
И уверен, такое решение на перле - это задача не для ЕГЭ.
В принципе алгоритм ясный и человек, знакомый хоть с одним языком способен его реализовать за отведенное время. 

Но одно дело программу на бейсике (НА БЕЙСИКЕ МОЖНО ВСЁ!) переписать в синтаксисе перла (оператор в оператор), другое дело писать "like perler", "like pythonista", "like fortran'tor"...

Comment: На бейсике можно всё, но это напоминает анекдот: "Могу копать, могу не копать -- А лестницу можешь? -- Могу, но долго копать". Так что от перлов/бейсиков, как я считаю, надо держаться подальше.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -alne 'push @{$h{sprintf "%.2f",($F[2]+$F[3]+$F[4])/3.0}}, "$F[0] $F[1]"; END{ print join "\n", map { join ", ", @{ $h{$_} } } ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h )[0..2] }'
```

Comment: Могуч язык perl ! 

И люди, **знающие его**, видимо предполагают, что подобная программа заведомо очевидна.

Comment: есть подозрение, что программа написанная на перле в другом стиле будет признана не удовлетворяющей условию "как можно более эффективная". жесть.

ЗЫ на сколько могу судить, для завершенности шедевра не хватает ввода данных и вывода остальных людей с одинаково низкими средними баллами, которые в тройку не вошли. Хотя про второе не уверен.

Comment: Вообще-то я имел в виду, что в ответе на форуме, было бы неплохо в качестве ликбеза как-то (желательно с обучающим уклоном) откомментировать такую прелесть.

Comment: согласен...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Скрипт выводит список учеников, набравших три самых худших балла (если такие есть). Доп. из 15 учеников 5 получили тройки, 5 -- четвёрки, 5 -- пятёрки. Результат -- все плохие. В %h будет три элемента, ключи 3, 4 и 5, а значения -- списки учеников с соответствующими баллами. Боюсь, что условию задачи это скрипт будет удовлетворять только в случае одного ученика, набравшего худший балл и одного -- чуть получше. (Третий снизу балл может набрать толпа, но вся она будет в результате).

Comment: В предыдущий не влезает. Может так?

       perl -alne 'push @{$h{sprintf "%.2f",($F[2]+$F[3]+$F[4])/3.0}}, "$F[0] $F[1]"; END{ print join "\n", map { join ", ", @{ $h{$_} } } grep {if ($i < 3 && $c < 3){$i++; $c+=$#{$h{$_}}+1}} ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h )[0..2] }'

Comment: Немного не так у вас получается.
Тестовые данные:

1.

 * 5 человек - средний балл 3
 * 1 человек - средний балл 4
 * 1 человек - средний балл 5

выведены должны быть 5-ро троечников, хорошисты и отличники не попадают в тройку худших.

2.

  * 2 человека - средний балл 3
  * 2 человека - средний балл 4
  * 2 человека - средний балл 5

выведены должны быть 4-ро с 3 и 4 баллами. 

3.

 * 1 человек - средний балл 3
 * 10 человек - средний балл 4
 * 50 человек средний балл 5

выведены должны быть 11 человек с 3-ой и 4-ой.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Это Вы кому адресовали?

Comment: @Yuri Вы меня совсем запутали. Про скрипт @Angr Bird я писал, что он выводит список получивших три наименьших средних балла. Т.е. для вот этих примеров -- выводятся все. Это не так? У меня получается что так.

Comment: Вы меня тоже запутали )) Проблема с перлом, ваш код понять не могу, поэтому и подумал неправильно. Сори.

Comment: @alexlz, разъясните, пожалуйста, вот это :

    {$c+=$#{$h{$_}}+1}

Answer (score 1):

Решение, конечно, кривое, не судите меня строго. Если придумаете более удачный алгоритм - перепишу. )))

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

$_ = "Иванов Петр 4 5 3
Сидоров Иван 2 4 5
Петров Павел 4 5 5
Адлор Дло 3 3 3
Лолщдшго Гшортт 3 3 3";

my @ar = split "\n", $_;
my %H;
foreach (@ar) {
    m/([à-ÿÀ-ß]+?)\s([à-ÿÀ-ß]+?)\s(\d)\s(\d)\s(\d)/;
    $H{GPA($3, $4, $5)} .= ' ' if $H{GPA($3, $4, $5)};
    $H{GPA($3, $4, $5)} .= ($1 . ' ' . $2);
}

@ar = keys %H;
my $min = min(@ar);
my $a1 = $H{$min};
delete $H{$min};
for (my $i=0;$i<@ar;$i++) { splice(@ar,$i,1) if $ar[$i]==$min }

$min = min(@ar);
my $a2 = $H{$min};
delete $H{$min};
for (my $i=0;$i<@ar;$i++) { splice(@ar,$i,1) if $ar[$i]==$min }

$min = min(@ar);
my $a3 = $H{$min};
delete $H{$min};
for (my $i=0;$i<@ar;$i++) { splice(@ar,$i,1) if $ar[$i]==$min }

print "<html><h1>$a1<br>$a2<br>$a3</h1></html>\n";

sub GPA {
   my $sum = 0;
   foreach (@_){
      $sum += $_;
   }
   return $sum/scalar @_;
}

sub min {
    my $min = $_[0];
    foreach (@_) {$min = $_ if $_ < $min}
    return $min;
}
```

Comment: В смысле ? Я вас не понял :)

Comment: Проехали, я исправил пост.

Answer (score 0):

Работа с хеш-массивами на Perl довольно неплохо описана [тут](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/perl_hash/). На правду вроде похоже. Пробуйте)

Так как список (файл данных) у вас *не* отсортированный (так как не сказано обратное), то красивое и быстрое решение тут придумать сложно...

Comment: Если для каждого ученика одна строка, то упорядоченность файла не имеет значения. В программе надо вести массив (в начале он пуст) из 3-х элементов для 3-х худших на данный момент по средему баллу и корректировать его для каждой прочитаной строки. 

В конце распечатать.

Т.е. сортировать (это насчет комментария @ikoolik к вопросу) вообще ничего не надо.

Но это, только, если по одной строке на ученика.

Comment: Только элементами должны быть тоже массивы - тех людей, чьи баллы совпадают. Это условие, что нужны все с одинаково низкими баллами, даже если их будет больше трех, несколько усложняет алгоритм.

Comment: Согласен. @alexlz и @arto создание массива и его сортировку по среднему баллу написали. Теперь надо просто научиться как в перле в цикле двигаться по массиву и печатать очередную строку. А как только балл изменился и уже вывели 3 или более строк, то останов. 

Или в нем (перле) это можно записать без явного цикла ?

Comment: @avp Ну во-первых на вводе есть неявный цикл по ключу -n. На выводе по map формируется список (по-вашему массив) содержащий представление строки для каждой оценки, а затем по join они объединяются в одну через разделитель `\n`. Три -- задаётся сечением списка ключей (sort ...)[0..2]. У Bird'а формируется хэш (ассоц. массив), где ключ -- средний балл, значение -- список строк (фам. им.). Затем в конце сортировка ключей этого хеша, и обработка для первых трёх. Я только добавил фильтр, чтобы следующая оценка не бралась, если уже три жертвы найдено.

Comment: @alexlz, посмотрите на комментарии @Yura Ivanov о **количестве жертв**. Их может оказаться больше (но не меньше 3-х).

По сути фильтр (я так понимаю, это {...} в grep) надо переделать (вычисление **c** внутри if в нем. 

На самом деле перл я *не знаю*, но в целом понятно, на уровне "читать", а вот "писать" не смогу.

Comment: @avp Похоже мы говорим на разных языка. Я пытался узнать у @Yuri, какие проблемы с тестами. У меня его тесты идут нормально. Чем не нравится grep с вычислением c внутри? (ни -w, ни use strict; в этом однострочнике нет). Кстати "фильтр" -- это именно grep (в других языках он обычно называется filter), а {} -- это блок, где вычисляется условие.

      , на уровне "читать", а вот "писать" не смогу

Круто. Как правило большинство перлописателей не могут читать скрипты. А писать -- пишут.

Comment: @alexlz, ну я же честно пишу **перл не знаю**. 

grep (он же фильтр (прекрасно понимаю)) с выражением внутри нравится (также понятно что он работает для строк, производимых sort из массива (списка) h и формат строк понятен) Непонятны манипуляции с переменной c (вначале она видимо 0, а потом непонятно на что увеличивается. Почему не $c+=1 ???). 

Насчет @Yura Ivanov (не @Yuri), он пишет: "нужны все с одинаково низкими баллами, даже если их будет больше трех". Мне кажется для этого надо:

    ... grep {if (лог выр см. ниже){$c+=1; p = $s; s = $F[0]}}...

в синтаксисе наверняка ошибки.

Comment: **Продолжение.**

p это средний балл в предыдущей строке, s в текущей F[0] онн же в текущей строке. Это в предположении что начальные значения переменных нули.

Что-то в таком духе. Черт в выражении логическая ошибка, а места там нет. Сейчас поправлю.

    $c < 3 || $p == $s

Comment: @avp `$c+=$#{$h{$_}}+1` в хеше %h -- пары средний-балл/список учеников, соответственно $h{$_} -- этот самый список. $#{$h{$_}} -- максимальный индекс в этом списке. Ну а +1--даёт длину списка (кол. учеников со ср. баллом $_ (здесь раб. переменная grep). $c не присвоена, если она участвует в операции (+), то ==0. (Использование неиниц. запрещается ключиком -w). Увеличивается на кол.(написал какое). Насчёт предложений по grep -- да, в синтаксисе бяка, но ещё: $F[0] на данный момент не существует (если существует -- то без смысла). autosplit имеет смысл только в цикле (-n) ввода.